# Hive regex for extracting keywords from url

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

**Filenames are following :**

1. `file:///storage/emulated/0/SHAREit/videos/Dangerous_Hero_(2017)____Latest_South_Indian_Full_Hindi_Dubbed_Movie___2017_.mp4`
2. `file:///storage/emulated/0/VidMate/download/%E0%A0_-_Promo_Songs_-_Khiladi_-_Khesari_Lal_-_Bho.mp4
   file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Video/VID-20171222-WA0015.mp4`
3. `file:///storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/%5DChitaChola%7B%7D%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B1%24%20.3gp`

I want to write hive regex to extract words from each string.

for example in 1st string **output should be : storage,emulated,....**

## UPDATE

This Code gives me result , but i wanted regex instead of below code.

```
package uri_keyword_extractor;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UDFUrlKeywordExtractor extends UDF {
    private  Text result = new Text();

    public  Text evaluate(Text url) {
        if (url == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String keywords = url_keyword_maker(url.toString());
        result.set(keywords);
        return result;
    }

    private static String url_keyword_maker(String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<String> keywordAr = new ArrayList<String>();
        char[] charAr = url.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < charAr.length; i++) {
            int current_index = i;
            // check if character is a-z or A-Z
            char ch = charAr[i];
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (current_index < charAr.length-1 && isChar(ch)) {
                sb.append(ch);
                current_index = current_index+1;
                ch = charAr[current_index];
            }
            String word = sb.toString();
            if (word.length() >= 2) {
                keywordAr.add(word);
            }
            i = current_index;
        }
        //
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i =0; i < keywordAr.size();i++) {
            String current = keywordAr.get(i);
            sb.append(current);
            if(i < keywordAr.size() -1) {
                sb.append(",");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static  boolean isChar(char ch) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int ascii_value = (int) ch;
        // A-Z => (65,90) a-z => (97,122)
        // condition 1 : A-Z , condition 2 : a-z character check
        if (  (ascii_value >= 65 && ascii_value <= 90)  ||  (ascii_value >= 97 && ascii_value <= 122) ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String test1 = "file:///storage/emulated/0/SHAREit/videos/Dangerous_Hero_(2017)____Latest_South_Indian_Full_Hindi_Dubbed_Movie___2017_.mp4";
        String test2 = "file:///storage/emulated/0/VidMate/download/%E0%A0_-_Promo_Songs_-_Khiladi_-_Khesari_Lal_-_Bho.mp4";
        String test3 = "file:///storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/%5DChitaChola%7B%7D%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B1%24%20.3gp";
        System.out.println(url_keyword_maker(test1).toString());
        System.out.println(url_keyword_maker(test2).toString());
        System.out.println(url_keyword_maker(test3).toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: you should provide full expected output .. it is too ambiguous

Comment: @hlagos see update

Comment: @wp78de see update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split(str, regex_pattern)` function, it splits str using regex as delimiter pattern and returns array. Then use `lateral view` + `epxlode` to explode array and filter keywords by length as in your Java code. Then apply `collect_set` to re-assemble array of keywords+`concat_ws(delimeter, str)` function to convert array to the delimited string if necessary.
The regex I passed to the `split` function is `'[^a-zA-Z]'`.

Demo:

```
select url_nbr, concat_ws(',',collect_set(key_word)) keywords from
(--your URLs example, url_nbr here is just for reference
select 'file:///storage/emulated/0/SHAREit/videos/Dangerous_Hero_(2017)____Latest_South_Indian_Full_Hindi_Dubbed_Movie___2017_.mp4' as url, 1 as url_nbr union all
select 'file:///storage/emulated/0/VidMate/download/%E0%A0_-_Promo_Songs_-_Khiladi_-_Khesari_Lal_-_Bho.mp4' as url, 2 as url_nbr union all
select 'file:///storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp%20Video/VID-20171222-WA0015.mp4' as url, 3 as url_nbr union all
select 'file:///storage/emulated/0/bluetooth/%5DChitaChola%7B%7D%D8%B9%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B1%24%20.3gp' as url, 4 as url_nbr)s
lateral view explode(split(url, '[^a-zA-Z]')) v as key_word
where length(key_word)>=2 --filter here
group by url_nbr
;
```

Output:

```
OK
1       file,storage,emulated,SHAREit,videos,Dangerous,Hero,Latest,South,Indian,Full,Hindi,Dubbed,Movie,mp
2       file,storage,emulated,VidMate,download,Promo,Songs,Khiladi,Khesari,Lal,Bho,mp
3       file,storage,emulated,WhatsApp,Media,Video,VID,WA,mp
4       file,storage,emulated,bluetooth,DChitaChola,gp
Time taken: 37.767 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)
```

Maybe I have missed something from your java code, but hope you have caught the idea, so you can easily modify my code and add additional processing if necessary.